# Apache HttpPost Multiple Files upload failes with server error - Missing initial multi part boundary

Tags: java, http, file-upload, apache-commons-httpclient

I try to upload multiple files, using Apache Http library.

```
   compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.6'
```

This is how I upload files.

```
String url = "url";
File f1 = new File("file1");
File f2 = new File("file2");
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic abcd=");
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

FileBody fileBody1 = new FileBody(f1, ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT);
FileBody fileBody2 = new FileBody(f2, ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT);

multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file_1_param", fileBody1);
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file_2_param", fileBody2);
HttpEntity httpEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
request.setEntity(httpEntity);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity == null) {
    return;
}

InputStream is = entity.getContent();
String textResponse = InputStreamUtils.readText(is);
System.out.println(textResponse);
```

It prints.

```
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Missing initial multi part boundary
at com.ca.devtest.acl.servlet.filters.RemoteAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RemoteAuthenticationFilter.java:285)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
```

**It works if I upload only one file though!**

Note, this is not a duplicate. These links show posts which refer the problem on the server side. This problem is with the client side.

[Jetty throws "Missing content for multipart request" on multipart form request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613104/jetty-throws-missing-content-for-multipart-request-on-multipart-form-request)

[500 Internal server error Android HttpPost file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550910/500-internal-server-error-android-httppost-file-upload)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out a resolution. I wanted to share it with other people, so you can 1) learn how to upload files and 2) pay attention to HTTP headers.

When I append `FileBody` to `MultipartEntityBuilder` it automatically sets boundary. I simply removed this line from the code

```
 request.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); //Remove it
```

[Example of a POST request with one or more files attached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517227/4587961)

[The Multipart Content-Type](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `content-type` option from the headers completely to make it work.

**Example**

```
headers = {
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW',
  'postman-token': '26ef68f6-e579-a029-aec2-09b291678b4d',
  'storeid': '4223556'
}
```